# Unity C# can you switch cameras in the scene without disabling one of the cameras?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two cameras in a scene and I want to switch between them without disabling them. Is it possible? If it is then can you show how it is done? Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to disable it? Leaving it enabled just wastes GPU cycles rendering something that won't be seen.

Comment: You would have a three port application 1) Connection to camera one 2) Connection to camera two 3) Output to scene.  You application will take one of the cameras as input and send to scene.

Comment: Not completely related (according to the selected answer) - I was looking at showing a specific camera in a scene view, already using cinemachine virtual cameras. Selecting the camera in the hierarchy and then going to `GameObject` => `Align view to selected` will show you that camera's view in the `Scene` window. Posting here because I landed here with my search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice way to use different cameras and manage transitions is using the Cinemachine package made by Unity. In the following animation I am switching between two Virtual Cinemachine Cameras by changing their priority.

[image: Switching between 2 Virtual Cinemachine Cameras by changing their priority.]

1. Create a new empty scene with the default camera.
2. Add a sphere to the center of the scene. This will be the object we want to look at with our cameras. Maybe also add a plane below the sphere like in the image above, for orientation.
3. Go to Window->Package Manager. Search for Cinemachine and install it.
4. Select the current Main Camera gameobject in your scene and add a CinemachineBrain component.
5. There is a new main menu entry called Cinemachine. Select "Create virtual camera" two times. Two gameobjects with a "Cinemachine Virtual Camera" Script will be added. The CinemachineBrain component acts as a coordinator for those Virtual Cameras.
6. Position the two Virtual Cameras in your scene and drag the Sphere into the "Look At" property of both Virtual Cameras.
7. If you start the project, the first Virtual Camera will be active. You can raise the "Priority" property of the second Virtual Camera and the view will transition to the second camera. Alternatively you can disable the first Virtual Camera.
8. Cinemachine is very powerful. You can change the transitions between Virtual Cameras in the CinemachineBrain component. Select a different "Default Blend" or add "Custom Blends" for transitions.
9. View some [Official Cinemachine Tutorials](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/cinemachine) to unleash their full power.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way is to disabling just the **Camera Component**.
I had a scene with 6 cameras with different post processing , one of my AA plugins was making game crash after disabling camera object , then I tried to only disabling **Camera Component**.

Now it works just fine :)

the second thought is just delete and adding **Camera Component** to camera objects using an script.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the Tag on the cameras. Usually the mainCam has the MainCamera tag.
I am not sure if that works tho..